# How SSIS Dataflow really works?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS package which transfers the data from one database to another.
The SSIS package runs on an application server.

I am thinking of moving one of the two databases to another data server. Will there be an impact in performance? How is the data flows in SSIS i.e. does all the data go in the application server where the SSIS runs and then to the destination database?

Comment: I don't know if it answers your exact question but I learned a lot from this blog post.  http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2007/10/09/SSIS_3A00_-Dataflow-mechanics.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSIS is a client-side process, so if it is running on a server other than the machine running the DBMS the traffic will be going over the network.  Your question is not very clearly worded, but I think you want to know whether moving a DB will affect performance given that the SSIS package is already running on a separate machine.

If the SSIS job is already running on an application server that is a physically separate machine to the DB server then moving one of the databases will probably not affect the performance unless it has a radically slower network connection than the other.

Comment: Yes my SSIS job runs on a physically separate machine from the dataserver. The two databases at the moment are on the same physical dataserver. I want to move the destination database to a different dataserver on the same network.

Comment: @koumides - Shouldn't make much difference, except that the load on the original DB server machine will be lower as the other DB has been moved off it.  If anything the SSIS job might run a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same situation and we upgraded our source system to a better configuration box. I didn't have to do anything on my part, but the data load times from the source to SQL box were cut down from approximately 40 minutes to under 12 minutes on average. To answer your question, you will only see any performance variance depending on 1) Your new systems resources and 2) If you make changes to the box hosting your SQL Server.